# phpMyAdmin - Status Monitor - System Resources not updating

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have recently upgraded my phpMyAdmin from 3.3x to 4.0.7. Everything is working great - except for the nifty Status --> Monitor --> System resource charts. The database charts are working fine. I've checked online resources and can't find any reference to a configuration parameter or specific permissions that need to be changed in order to enable these.

Any ideas on how to enable the "System CPU Usage", "System Memory", and "System Swap" monitor charts?

OS: CentOS 6.4 | PHP: 5.3.27 | Database: MariaDB 5.5.32 | phpMyAdmin: 4.0.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FIXED! [Tyron's script](http://pastebin.com/Z5hbWhfk) revealed the problem: an error message thrown when attempting to access the `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/stat` files via the script (and phpMyAdmin)

```
open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/proc/meminfo) is not within the allowed path
```

With this clue, I was able to tweak the account's `php.ini` settings (this is a cPanel server, so used the [PHP open_basedir Tweak](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/TweakPhp)) and voila! the data is available. THANK YOU!

Comment: Tyron's script also helped me fix this on Ubuntu Server 13.10.  I appended `:/proc/meminfo:/proc/stat` to the `open_basedir` directive (line 18 at the time of this writing) in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` and ran a `sudo service apache2 reload`

Answer (score 5):

It's possible that CentOS is simply not supported, though some googling suggest that it should work. Two conditions have to apply for it to work:

- /proc/meminfo and /proc/stat need to be readable
- the constant PHP_OS (which is according to google populated by the **uname** command) has to be set to Linux in your case

If both of these conditions apply to your system: Do you see any errors in your Browsers Javascript console when you open the monitor?

The code responsible for it is in libraries/sysinfo.lib.php, if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you, Tyron. Both /proc/meminfo and /proc/stat carry 444 perms and are readable; 'uname' returns "Linux" - so that doesn't appear to be the issue.  

There are no Javascript errors being reported and I can see the AJAX responses coming back from the server. The JSON elements for CPU and Memory are being returned, but with NULL values.

Its very strange - as CentOS (RedHat Enterprise) is surely supported, yet there are no other reports of this issue to be found via Google.

Comment: Can you show us the output of this php script: http://pastebin.com/dwHpFygN - you'd need to create a sysinfotest.php file in your phpMyAdmin folder and call it directly from the browser. Don't forget to delete the file again once you're done, otherwise it could potentially allow unsecured access to your cpu/memory usage.

Comment: @Tyron: I'm seeing the same problem, but on Ubuntu 12.04. Running the script produces this output: `PHP_OS is Linux 

result of PMA_getSysInfoOs(): Linux

result of PMA_getSysInfo(): PMA_SysInfo Object
(
    [os] => Linux
)


result of $sysinfo->supported(): 1

result of $sysinfo->loadavg(): Array
(
    [loadavg] => 0
)


result of $sysinfo->memory(): Array
(
)`

Comment: Please try this script: http://pastebin.com/Z5hbWhfk - I added 2 lines to display any PHP Errors that might occur.

Comment: The script revealed that the problem was related to open_basedir. I added `:/proc/meminfo:/proc/stat` to the `php_admin_value open_basedir` line in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf on my Ubuntu 12.04 server and restarted Apache, and all the monitor charts are now working.

Comment: Thank you all! In my case, I use `nginx` with `php-fpm` but the principle is the same, you can change the `open_basedir` placing those two paths under the `php_admin_value[open_basedir] =` variable on the FPM pool configuration file that, under Ubuntu, ought to be somewhere in `/etc/php/7.X/fpm/pool.d/`

Answer (score 1):

sharing with those who run phpMyAdmin on windows, my charts (System CPU usage, System memory, System swap) showed no data before, just fix it by enabling extension php_com_dotnet.dll in php.ini